# Border radius second statement followed by / in css

Tags: css

I was looking for css code for smileys. I have found it on http://bavotasan.com/2010/draw-smiley-face-css3/. They have used border radius for that. I am confused with second statement for border radius followed by `/`

```
border-radius:0 0 120px 120px / 0 0 90px 90px
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second statement is for a second radius. This can be used to make the curvature eliptical.

```
div {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:#00FF00;
  border-radius: 30px/10px; /* horizontal radius / vertical radius */
}
```

[like this](http://jsfiddle.net/cp241kfu/)